# FFmpeg av_read_frame and maximum packet size

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, frame, decode

Any possibility to detect maximum packet (AVpacket) size that **av_read_frame()** can read?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same recently.  It appears that av_read_frame internally calls a codec specific read_packet function for each codec/format. This in turns allocate memory per packet and frees it depending on the maximum limits that the codec/format poses. So as long as you have memory to support the (in)valid stream you should be fine and the limits are specific to the codec/format decoders.  [YOu can find the function defined in AVInputFormat for each format as .read_packet ].

Comment: Good point. I already asked developers of ffmpeg about limitation and they said it limited by: 1) MAX_INT bound 2) codec limitation (like you said) 3) even video file limitation in some cases

Comment: @jAckOdE, you cannot do it that way. You will have to go and check for the codec in the code.

Comment: sorry, i'm kinda new to this, so bear with me. Can you be more specific? what properties should i check if i have the codec context and the codec?